# Core Data: How to check if data is in consecutive dates?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I am saving core data after a user completes a 'workout' and want to be able to check if the dates the user has worked out are in a consecutive order. I have used the code below to check if the user has worked out on a day that is clicked on a calender, but cannot think how to check if the days are consecutive.

At first I was thinking of taking the .Day of the saved NSDate and see if the days are in order, but this would not work for consecutive days when the month changes e.g. from the 31st to the 1st of a month.

```
let appDel: AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
let context: NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext

OuterLoop:  do {
    let request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Workout")
    let workoutResults = try context.executeFetchRequest(request) as! [Workout]

    if workoutResults.count > 0 {
        for item in workoutResults {
            let workoutDateDay = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().component(.Day, fromDate: item.workoutDate!)

            if workoutDateDay == dayView.date.day {

                let convertedTime:Int = Int(item.workoutTime!)
                let convertedNumberOfWorkouts: Int = Int(item.workoutNumber!)
                tempArray.append(convertedTime)
                tempArrayWorkoutNumber.append(convertedNumberOfWorkouts)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
func consecutiveDatesCheck(dateArray: [NSDate]) -> Int {

    // The incoming parameter dateArray is immutable, so first make it mutable
    var mutableArray = dateArray

    // Next, sort the incoming array
    mutableArray.sortInPlace({ $0.compare($1) == NSComparisonResult.OrderedAscending })

    var x = 0
    var numberOfConsecutiveDays = 1
    var streakArray = [Int]()

    // Cycle through the array, comparing the x and x + 1 elements
    while x + 1 < mutableArray.count {

        let calendar: NSCalendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
        let components = calendar.components(.Day, fromDate: mutableArray[x], toDate: mutableArray[x + 1], options: [])

        // If the difference between the dates is greater than 1, append the streak to streakArray and reset the counter
        if abs(components.day) > 1 {
            streakArray.append(numberOfConsecutiveDays)
            numberOfConsecutiveDays = 1
        }

        // If the difference between the days is exactly 1, add one to the current streak
        else if abs(components.day) == 1 {
            numberOfConsecutiveDays += 1
        }

        x += 1
    }

    // Append the final streak to streakArray
    streakArray.append(numberOfConsecutiveDays)
    print(streakArray)

    // Return the user's longest streak
    return streakArray.maxElement()!
}
```

then when calling the function:

```
   do {
        let request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Workout")
        let workoutResults = try context.executeFetchRequest(request) as! [Workout]

        if workoutResults.count > 0 {

            // Declare a new empty array
            var dateArray = []

            for item in workoutResults {
                dateArray.append(item.workoutDate!)
            }

            consecutiveDatesCheck(dateArray)
        }
    } catch {
        print("Error loading data")
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this works well for 2 dates, but how could I customise this code to check if more than 2 dates (e.g. 10 dates) are in a row?

Comment: Trying it now, I am struggling with how to add the core data parameter into your function. My entity name is Workout, and it has two attributes; workoutDate and workoutTime. workoutDate is of type NSDate and these are the values I want to check are in order.

Comment: Check the few lines I added to the beginning of the code. That should allow you to create an array of NSDate from your core data entities

Comment: I've added your code and some core data to test it but the code when executed is not printing anything, not sure why. (thanks for your help so far)

Comment: If you upload your project to GitHub or BitBucket I'd be happy to take a look. CoreData can be tricky to get set up properly.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is for some dates I have multiple core data entries, but not sure how I would delete the extra entries.

Comment: I added a print message in the 'if abs(components.day) != 1' function and it always executes this code, even when I print the core data and the first 3 values are all consecutive. This suggests the components.day value isnt being executed properly?

Comment: Addressing the issue regarding multiple entries for the same date -- you could write code to delete the extra entries, but I think it would be easier to change "if abs(components.day) != 1" to "if abs(components.day) > 1", that way if the difference is zero (i.e. the dates are the same) or if the difference is one (i.e. the dates are consecutive) the function will still provide you the desired output

Comment: That's a good first step at debugging. Now try adding print(components.day) to see what the actual results are.

Comment: print(components.day) returns 0. print(components) returns <NSDateComponents: 0x7ff848dd8040>
    Day: 0.

Comment: Also, what is your reasoning for storing workoutDate and workoutTime as two different entities? I would think it would be more concise to store one NSDate and then pull the relevant components from that one entity.

Comment: workoutTime isnt referring to a date, it refers to the total time worked out e.g. 1 minute. Probably should of named it something more clear!

Comment: I would expect print(components.day) to return 0 when the dates are equal. I'm running the code in a playground with dummy data and seeing the expected results... Are you sure that your core data entries are from different dates? You can change the system date on your computer/phone to simulate inputing data from the past/future

Comment: Ahh, I see :) Yeah, perhaps workoutDuration would be more appropriate. But now that I know that it makes sense.

Comment: My core data entries from various run throughs of my app are on different dates, however there are multiple entries for some dates where the user has worked out more than once. Would this cause the problems?

Comment: would there be a way to filter out entries if there was more than one for each date?

Comment: If you change the code so that it reads "if abs(components.day) > 1", this shouldn't cause a problem.

Comment: Of course there's a way to filter entries for more than one date, but since it's not necessary for your code to function as desired, I wouldn't recommended adding it just for fun :P

Comment: But then that would show every results, and wouldnt distinguish between the different days would it?

Comment: The function first puts the entries in order. Then it checks each entry against the next entry. If they are the same date, then the absolute difference of components.day is 0. If they are consecutive dates, the absolute difference of components.day is 1. Only if the two consecutive entries are more than one day apart does the function return false.

Comment: When I run the code it returns a final value of 23, when the number of consecutive days worked out is 5, but the number of workouts in those days is 23. So I would need a way of making there only one entry per day.

Comment: By the way, I really appreciate how much effort you have gone through for me here!

Comment: Post your updated code. I'm having a hard time following from your descriptions

Comment: No problem! Or email me your project and I'll be happy to take a look. austin at austinkwood dot com

Comment: print(x) will always return the number of items in the array, it's simply a variable used to cycle through each element. What result do you want from the function? A boolean, telling you whether all the entries occur on consecutive days? Or do you want an integer, telling the number of consecutive days in a row?

Comment: Also, where are you declaring dateArray? I would declare a new empty array somewhere in the do block

Comment: It is declared outside of the do loop in the view controller

Comment: As things are set up now, if you load core data more than once, you'll have duplicate entries in dateArray. Two ways to solve this. Method 1, you can add "dateArray.removeAll()" prior to "for item in workResults". Method 2, you can declare dateArray inside the do block so that it is emptied automatically each time. Use the first method if you need to access the results outside the consecutiveDatesCheck() function, otherwise use the second, as it saves one line of code

Comment: Ive moved the dateArray declaration inside the do block, but the code is still returning 23 ( the number of workouts in the 5 consecutive days, instead of returning 5 (the number of consecutive days).

Comment: You didn't answer my previous question about Bool or Int, but now I think I understand what you want. Give me a couple minutes, I think it should be easy to solve

Comment: See the updated code. Added the variable numberOfConsecutiveDays. This should return 5. You'll probably still have to massage the code a bit to serve your exact purposes (I'm not sure exactly what they are). For example, instead of "return false" you might want to append the current value of numberOfConsecutiveDays to an array and then reset the value to 1. This would be useful if a user has several weeks of data and you want to tell them their longest streak.

Comment: Haha I tried the exact same thing earlier, even down to the same variable name! For some reason the code else if abs(components.day) == 1 {
                numberOfConsecutiveDays += 1
                print("YES")
                
            }
never gets executed

Comment: Actually, I was curious how to do this and decided to play around. Turns out it wasn't that hard! Let me know if that works for you. Note: the function now returns an integer (the user's longest streak) rather than a boolean.

Comment: Not sure why but my answer is returning [1,1] instead of 5.

Comment: That's odd... do me a favor and add print(dateArray) right before "consecutiveDatesCheck(dateArray)" in your do block. I'm curious what the data looks like that your passing into the function

Comment: [2016-08-20 06:38:23 +0000, 2016-08-20 06:43:59 +0000, 2016-08-20 06:49:19 +0000, 2016-08-20 06:58:59 +0000, 2016-08-20 07:05:44 +0000, 2016-08-20 09:05:25 +0000, 2016-09-02 12:05:55 +0000, 2016-09-02 17:39:01 +0000, 2016-09-03 13:37:31 +0000, 2016-09-03 13:41:10 +0000, 2016-09-03 13:59:36 +0000, 2016-09-03 14:26:11 +0000, 2016-09-03 14:48:57 +0000, 2016-09-03 14:51:25 +0000, 2016-09-03 15:06:56 +0000, 2016-09-03 15:15:00 +0000, 2016-09-04 13:53:48 +0000, 2016-09-04 13:56:13 +0000, 2016-09-04 14:16:29 +0000, 2016-09-04 17:33:16 +0000, 2016-09-05 16:53:32 +0000, 2016-09-06 12:20:16 +0000]

Comment: (I had to cut out some of the values as the comment was too long)

Comment: Hmm that's odd. I wouldn't expect that data to give you the results you're getting. Without actually looking at the project files, I'm at a loss for what to try next. Sorry!